# What mechanisms exist to ensure the privacy of web application user data?

Tags: database-design, privacy

What mechanisms exist, if any, to protect a user's privacy and data for web applications? I ask because I would like to create one myself, and was wondering if there's any way of guaranteeing my users their privacy beyond my word that I wouldn't look in the database. I imagine big companies have complicated procedures and a way of locking down their data, but how does a single person, or a small startup do it?

I'm planning on using Google App Engine. I mention it in case that can offer a solution.

To clarify, I'm asking less about security measures I can employ to protect data from third-parties, and more about measures I can employ to guarantee users' privacy from myself / other server administrators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic tools: encryption and hashing.

Encryptiong comes in two flavors: Symmetric where the same key is used for encryption and decryption.

PKI where you have two keys and what ever you encrypt with one you can decrypt with the other and vice versa.

Hashing converts some data into a more or less unique number or String without a feasible way back.

Depending on what you actually want to protect you can use these tool to obtain almost anything you need.

Examples: Passwords get stored as hashes. To check a password convert it again and compare it to the hashes => You as the application provide don't have the password.

You have the application create a key for each user and encrypt everything you want to protect from your own eyes with that key. The challenge is that now the user has to keep that key secret and protected, which users aren't very good at. Also searching this kind of encrypted data is bound to be really slow.

Possibly the biggest risk to private data are hacks against your application. Spend some time on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) to learn about the most important attacks and how to fight them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have seen, it is mainly by use of legal terms of service where the user enters into a legally binding agreement with the service or company to set what they will and will not do with their data.

Another thing is that for certain things like credit card processing and such there are standards of use such as having a system where access can be audited (i.e. it keeps track of every access to a file, modifications, and who did it). Also, sensitive/confidential data is usually is kept on a separate server from the public one so that those from the outside don't directly touch the server and have to go through a go-between server. Also, physically most server rooms are kept under lock and key. Many places have a keypad which records which codes are used to access the rooms.

Also, make sure to encrypt sensitive/private data. You can set up a system where private data is encrypted using a salt string based on the hash of the user's password or something (of course, if they changed their password that would require that you decrypt and re-encrypt their data). That way, even you looking casually at the database wouldn't see their data. Now, that would only really be suitable for a data storage situation since many times they are giving you information so that you can use it. Passwords should ALWAYS be hashed, though. Never put them in clear text.

Credit card numbers on commercial systems are hashed using a salt string that changes every so often. The string is just stored on the same server somewhere (at least it is on the systems I have seen...other larger commercial ones probably protect it better), but access to the server is extremely limited. Programs needing to know credit card information get to authenticate to that server and the server will use its hash string to decrypt the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1) always use https for sending/receiving any confidential data,

2) always store passwords as a hash (never clear text),

3) Never trust, and always carefully validate, your input

4) always code your web pages to protect against [cross-site scripting](http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html) and [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx).

And post an explicit "confidentiality policy".  Here's an example:

- http://www.promoteitplease.com.au/legal-notices/privacy-policy.html

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I am mostly concerned in stuff like the privacy policy sample you followed. I am curious what actual power or obligations posting such a policy would have.

Answer (score 0):

There are four techniques I can think of.

1. encrypt data using some trivial function like rot13.  This protects against accidental reading of confidential data, but that's all.
2. encrypt sensitive data.  Keep the data and the encryption key separate - if you can, arrange it so that the person administering the server(s) with the keys are different people from the ones administering the server(s) with the data.
3. Restrict access to sensitive information only to those who need it.  Segment data into separate partitions and make differerent partitions accessible by different parties.  For example, you could store a person's medical history in one database where their actual name isn't stored but the records are identified by some identifier, and the actual names are stored in another database with the same identifier.  A person would need access to both databases to be able to link histories to people.  Of course both pieces would need to be combined at some point, and someone is going to need to admin the system where this happens.
4. (This is the usual corporate strategy) Enforce protection of customer information through policy and contract.  Keep employees educated about the value of confidential information, and the consequences of not protecting it.  You may be able to make employees legally liable for causing breaches of company policy. I Am Not A Lawyer.